# Very slow resource loading time with compojure route/resources and ring

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript, ring, compojure

Disclaimer: I am very new to clojure.

I am suddenly running into a issue where loading my clojurescript app takes over 15 seconds just to load all of the library code. A second project, set up the same way, is not having these issues.

[image]

CLJS build:

```
  :cljsbuild {:builds [{:id "dev"
                        :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
                        :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/app/js/app.js"
                                   :output-dir "resources/public/app/js/out"
                                   :optimizations :none
                                   :source-map true}}]}
```

handler.clj

```
  (GET  "/" [] (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public/app"}))
  (route/resources "/" {:root "public/app"})
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))
```

My first thought is, that it somehow re-compiles everything every time I access the page, but the file timestamps of unchanged libraries didn't change.

Second thought was, that it is probably because of cache killing in my browser, but even after allowing cache through the developer tools, file loading time is still snailspeed.

Third thought was the compojure version difference between the 2 projects, but even after upgrading the 2nd project to latest, or downgrading 1st project to previous version, the issue still persists.

When monitoring, I also noticed the java process to jump to 350% CPU on page access.

I tried to revert all changes I made but can't figure out where the problem is. Being very new to clojure and clojurescript, I am out of ideas. I obviously can't wait 15 seconds with every page load just to see a message in the console.

**/ EDIT:**

Project.clj

```
(defproject picky "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "project"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :source-paths ["src/clj"]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.reader "0.8.2"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2371"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.3.1"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.3.1"]
                 [compojure "1.2.1"]
                 [korma "0.4.0"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.2-1002-jdbc4"]
                 [com.cemerick/friend "0.2.1"]
                 [lobos "1.0.0-beta3"]
                 [cljs-http "0.1.20"]
                 [secretary "1.2.1"]
                 [om "0.3.6"]
                 [com.facebook/react "0.8.0.1"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.5"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.3"]
            [lein-ring "0.8.13"]
            [lein-pdo "0.1.1"]]
  :aliases  {"up"  ["pdo" "cljsbuild" "auto" "dev," "ring" "server-headless"]}
  :ring {:handler myapp.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring-mock "0.1.5"]]}}
  :cljsbuild {:builds [{:id "dev"
                        :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
                        :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/app.js"
                                   :output-dir "resources/public/js/out"
                                   :optimizations :none
                                   :source-map true}}]}
```

Middlewares are `wrap-json-body` and `wrap-json-response`, although I tried already disabling both.

Comment: This is not a lot of information to go on. Could you paste your project.clj? Alternatively, what versions of Ring/Compojure/Clojure/Java you're using, which middlewares you're applying, what HTTP server is serving your app, etc... The snippets you pasted look fine, the problem could basically lie anywhere in your pipeline. :)

Comment: @xsc pasted the entire project.clj file. I am serving everything over the default ring server-headless since the project is still in early development. Middlewares are `wrap-json-body` and `wrap-json-response`, but removing both didn't help. Plus the 2nd project is using both as well without any issues. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I see that you're loading 129 files and that might be putting some stress on the server (although it shouldn't). I.e., if each file takes 100ms to load and the server serves them sequentially, you might end up where you are now. But that's an unsubstantiated guess at best.

Comment: found the source of the problem. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the culprit of this huge performance loss. After a ton of debugging I found out that the only difference between project 1 and project 2 is the resources folder.

Project 1 includes a entire frontend project. A lot of files through bower, scss, compiled css, compiled cljs and so on. Everything you need for good frontend development. In total **10506** files.

Project 2 was a test project including a few HTML, javascript and compiled cljs files. **142** files in total.

For testing, I moved some files out of the resources folder and ta-daa, file load is down to a few milliseconds. Move the files back into the resources folder, performance get tanked up.

I am going to file a bug report at the compojure project. Might be something they weren't aware of yet.

Comment: Not really a bug then, is it? If you're serving a lot of data you have to wait for it to arrive.

Comment: I am not accessing the files at the same time so I honestly don't think just the existence of files in the filesystem should cause such a big performance drop. Anyway, after submitting the issue to compojure, it turned out to be related to the amount of files in java's class path

Comment: I see. Interesting that resource lookup times can be influenced by the number of available files. I'd expect it to deteriorate if a lot of JARs' indices would have to be examined but not in this case. Will keep it in mind, thanks for following up on this. :)